# How to assign cell value depending on row and column header in vue js table

Tags: vue.js, html-table, vuejs2

For my table, below is the code to display its components:

```
<tbody style="border-bottom:#dbb100 1px"  v-for="(item,itm_index) in itemList" :key="itm_index.id" >
      <tr class="left-align">
           <td>{{item.name}}</td>
           <td v-for="(day, day_index) in days" :key="day_index.id" v-if="getTotalWork(itm_index, day_index)==true">{{newValue}}</td>
      </tr>
</tbody>
```

And this is my method that supposedly updates the value on it's corresponding rows and columns.

```
getTotalWork(item_index, day_index) {
        let item = this.itemList[item_index];
        let day = this.days[day_index];
        let getDate = this.template.date;
        item = item.name;

        if(this.costList.length > 0){
            if(day < 10) day = '0'+day;
            var searchItem = this.costList.find(emp => emp.name === item);

                if(searchItem.name == item && searchItem.date ==this.monthYear+'-'+day){
                    this.newValue = searchItem.total_work;
                }else{
                    this.newValue = 0;
                }
        }
        return true;
    },
```

My problem now is that, instead of updating it's corresponding columns and rows only, it updates all of it with one value which is the value of an item. Below is the sample output:

[image]

My question is, how can I just update the corresponding cell only based on the `item_index` and `day_index` passed value. Passed value of this parameters are row and column headers. Expected output should not be `499` only, there should be like other digits.

Any idea how can I attain this? Been stucked here for almost a day and haven't found any luck in my searches.

**EDIT**

I don't know how to make a fiddle but the output is like this when I `console.log(this.costList)`:

```
1:
   date: "2018-07-01"
   name:"John Doe"
   total_work:240
2:
   date: "2018-07-02"
   name:"John Doe"
   total_work:242
3:
   date: "2018-07-03"
   name:"John Doe"
   total_work:243
```

Comment: Someone has any idea how can I do this, please? Thanks.

Comment: your getTotalWork function always returns true, is it correct?

Comment: @MaxSinev Yes, but if I return false, no value is displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make `getTotalWork` to return value and place it in output:

```
<tbody style="border-bottom:#dbb100 1px"  v-for="(item,itm_index) in itemList" :key="itm_index.id" >
  <tr class="left-align">
       <td>{{item.name}}</td>
       <td v-for="(day, day_index) in days" :key="day_index.id">{{getTotalWork(itm_index, day_index)}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

So your function will be something like this:

```
getTotalWork(item_index, day_index) {
    let item = this.itemList[item_index];
    let day = this.days[day_index];
    let getDate = this.template.date;
    item = item.name;

    //MAX SINEV's answer  
    if(this.costList.length > 0){
        if(day < 10) day = '0'+day;
        var searchItem = this.costList.find(emp => emp.name === item);

            if(searchItem.name == item && searchItem.date ==this.monthYear+'-'+day){
                return searchItem.total_work;
            }else{
                return 0;
            }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**OP's REVISION:**

```
if(this.costList.length > 0){

    if(day < 10){
        day = '0'+day;
    }
    //this.monthYear contains year and date in yyyy-mm format
    var searchItem = this.costList.find(emp => emp.name === item.name && emp.date == this.monthYear+'-'+day);

    if(typeof searchItem != 'undefined'){
        return searchItem.total_work;
    }
}
return 0;
```

Comment: I will get back to you. Currently verifying the output. Thanks for this man!

Comment: My problem with this now is that when it gets the data that has value, it will not proceed to next one. For example Max has data in july 1 and july 2 and july 3, july 1 is only executed and july 2  and is not, as a result, it displays 0.

Comment: @ramedju can you provide how your data organized or some jsfiddle with reproduced issue?

Comment: I don't know how to make a JS fiddle but I have provided some data output on my edit above. That is supposed to display data from July1-3, but July 1 is the only date that has data others are 0. Thanks.

Comment: I can't find any idea why is it not iterating to the other dates, of a specific name,

Comment: I will add my piece of code to your answer to attain what I really want that already works now. Thanks man